# How to show the following ideal is or isn't maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$I$ is an ideal of $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. If $I$ is the set of polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(3)$ is even. I know that if $R/I$ is a field, then it is maximal. I just don't know how this quotient ring is defined or how exactly to implement that fact.

Comment: Consider the composition $\mathbb{Z}[X]\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. The first map is evaluation, the second map is projection.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very elementary argument: If $p \notin I$, we have $p(3)$ odd. So $p(3)-1$ is even, hence $p-1 \in I$.

For the quotient we deduce If: $p \neq 0$, then $p=1$. Hence $R/I=\{0,1\} = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

It is also very easy to show $I=(2,x-3)$. Clearly $(2,x-3) \subset I$. On the other hand, if $p \in I$, we have $h = p+2n$ with $h(3)=0$ for some integer $n$, since $p(3)$ is even. From $h(3)=0$, we deduce $h = (x-3) \cdot g$, so we have $$p=(x-3) \cdot g - 2n \in (2,x-3)$$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Show that the kernel of  $\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, $p\mapsto p(3)+2\mathbb Z$ is $I$.

Comment: Ok, so I see that after I prove that I use the first isomorphism theorem?